# childrens of a pointer pointing to a Node are always set to NULL

Tags: c++, pointers, null

I'm creating a game with AI using recursive calling, I have a struct called "Node" , when filling them with new int[5][5] they are filled but when I return and call other function like
when I call a fun called "bestMove" to loop within childrens THEY are all pointing to NULL, for example:

```
struct Node 
{
    int state[5][5];
    Node* parent;
    Node* child[20];
    Node()
    {
     parent = NULL;
     for(int i=0;i<=19;i++)
         child[i] = NULL;
    }

    Node(Node* father)
    {
     parent = father;
     for(int i=0;i<=19;i++)
         child[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void fill_new_state(Node* childPointer)
{
    if(everything is Ok) //and its Okay
    childPointer = new Node();//with linking to parent and all...
    childPointer->state[row][col] = bla bla bla//fill 
    return;
}

void expandChildern(Node* root)
{
    fill_new_state(root->child[i])//looping
}

void bestMove(Node* root)
{
    Node* best = root->child[0] //if not null and it is not null
    //loop and chose the best 
    root = best
}

void main()
{
    Node* root = new Node();
    expandChildren(root);
    bestMove(root);
}
```

in the function `fill_new_state(Node* childPointer)` the child is filled and it is not NULL
but after returning from `fill_new_state(Node* childPointer)` exactly in the function `expandChildren(Node* root)` the child is NULL.

Comment: Unable to reproduce error. The posted code is not functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in the function fill_new_state(Node* childPointer) the child is filled
>   and it is not NULL but after returning from fill_new_state(Node*
>   childPointer) exactly in the function expandChildren(Node* root) the
>   child is NULL.

That's because you passed the pointer by value, which makes a copy of the pointer.  Then inside fill_new_state you set the copy to point to the new Node object, but that has no effect on any other pointers outside the function.

It's equivalent to doing this:

```
void foo(int val)
{
   val = val + 1;
}

void bar()
{
   int x = 5;
   foo(x);
   // You can't expect x to be 6 here, because foo() incremented a
   // copy of x, not the original x.
}
```

The way to get the behavior you want is to pass the pointer argument by reference instead:

```
void fill_new_state(Node* & childPointer)
```

... that way any changes made to the pointer inside fill_new_state() will be visible in the calling context as well -- i.e. root->child[i] will be set non-NULL when fill_new_state returns.